# Proof of Maschke's theorem (KG-invariant)

Tags: representation-theory

I'm studying Maschke's theorem  but I don't understand some basic things about the proof.
The theorem tells that if G is a finite group and K a field with $car K\neq 0$ or $car K = p$ which does not divide $|G|$, then every KG-module M is semisimple (which means that every submodule has a complementary submodule). 
The proof says: "because M is also a vector space, every submodule $M_1$ of $M$ has a complement in $M$, so that $M=M_1 \oplus M_2$. However $M_2$ is not necessarily KG-invariant and this becomes what we need to prove."
What I don't understand is why being KG-invariant is the same of being a submodule. What does really "KG-invariant" mean? Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Being $KG$ invariant means that if you multiply an element of $M_2$ by some scalar from $KG$, the result is still in $M_2$. That is,
$$\forall\alpha\in KG\;\forall x\in M_2:\alpha x\in M_2.$$
This is precisely the condition for a subspace to be a submodule.

---

**Edit:** A $KG$-homomorphism is a function $f:M\to N$, where $M,N$ are $KG$-modules, such that $f$ is a homomorphism of additive groups and
$$\forall\alpha\in KG\;\forall x\in M:f\left(\alpha x\right)=\alpha f\left(x\right).$$

How does the proof of Maschke's Theorem goes? We take a projection $\pi:M\to M_1$ as $K$-vector spaces. That is, $\pi^2=\pi$, $\mathrm{Im}\left(\pi\right)=M_1$ and $\pi|_{M_1}=\mathrm{Id}_{M_1}$. This may be a homomorphism of vector spaces, but we want a $KG$-homomorphism, so we take
$$\tilde{\pi}\left(x\right)=\frac{1}{\left|G\right|}\sum_{g\in G}g\pi\left(xg^{-1}\right).$$
This turns out to be a $KG$-homomorphism, which is also a projection -- $\tilde{\pi}^2=\tilde{\pi}$, $\mathrm{Im}\left(\tilde{\pi}\right)=M_1$ and $\tilde{\pi}|_{M_1}=\mathrm{Id}_{M_1}$.

Now, all that is left is to prove that
$$M=M_1\oplus\ker\tilde{\pi}.$$
This shows that every submodule of $M$ has a complement, making $M$ semisimple.

Comment: Thanks for the precise answer! Can I also ask you how is this connected to the notion of "KG-homomorphism"? I mean, in the following part of the proof it is proved that the function $\pi=\frac{1}{|G|}\sum_{x\in G}x\pi x^{-1}$ is a KG-homomorphism. How does this information help for the proof?

Comment: @xyzt I edited my answer and added an explanation and the proof of Maschke's Theorem.

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer, but there's a thing I still don't understand :( Why do we need $\tilde\pi$ to be a KG-homomorphism while being a homomorphism is not enough?

Comment: @xyzt If $\tilde{\pi}$ is a $KG$-homomorphism, its kernel will be a $KG$-submodule of $M$. If $\tilde{\pi}$ is just a homomorphism of vector spaces, it may not be closed under multiplication by $KG$.

Comment: Perfect! I totally understand! Thanks again for your patience and precision!

Answer (score 0):

You have $M$ which is a $KG$-module; it is a vector space over $K$
and $gm$ is a well-defined element of $M$ for $g\in G$ and $m\in M$ etc.

$M_1$ is a $KG$-submodule; it is a vector subspace of $M$ **and**
$gm\in M_1$ whenever $g\in G$ and $m\in M_1$.

Vector subspaces always have complements; there is a vector subspace
$M_2$ with $M_1+M_2=M$ and $M_1\cap M_2=\{0\}$. **But** a priori,
$M_2$ may not be a $KG$-submodule; there may be $g\in G$ and $m\in M_2$
with $gm\notin M_2$.

The proof of Maschke's theorem shows that one can replace $M_2$
by another complement $M_2'$ which **is** a $KG$-submodule.